# Real analysis. Functions with compact support.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers, then exists a function $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support such that $f^{(n)}(0)=a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Since this problem belongs to the Taylor polynomial chapter, my first attempt consisted in considering the Taylor polynomial centered at $0$. We know that $f$ has compact support, then $f$ is bounded and $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Using the infinitesimal formula we have that $f(0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(0)\frac{(0-x_0)^n}{n!}$ or every $x_0$. So, for every iteration, we have constants $a_0, a_1, ..., a_n$ such that $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. Can I just say: let $a_n = n!a_n$? Here I don't know how to keep on (if I'm in the right path at all). I would really appreciate if someone could help me or give a hint.

Comment: Probably the question is meant to require that the compactly supported function is _not_ the identically-zero function... yet all its Taylor-Maclaurin coefficients at $0$ are $0$. So, evidently, $f$ is _not_ represented by its infinite Taylor expansion at $0$. It's not so easy to concoct such an example.

Comment: The Taylor polynomial approach won't work here. Just note that if $a_n = (n!)^2$ (I mean the original sequence -- you've used the notation $a_n$ twice), then your Taylor series becomes $\sum n!x^n$, which does not converge for non-zero $n$. So the question will need a more sophisticated tool to answer than the Taylor polynomial.

Comment: This is a result, a very nice one, of Borel.

Comment: Well the use of the Taylor polynomial is not required. Is just the tool we had, we can use whatever we want to proove the stament, as long as we use real analysis results.

Comment: If $f$ is such an example, then $f$ cannot be analytic because if $f$ is analytic and there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)=0$ and $(x_n)$ has cluster point, then $f$ is identically zero. Since the support of $f$ is compact, such sequence obviously exists. In another word, we need to consider $C^\infty$ function that is not analytic.